# Running django webapp on apache using mod_wsgi

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I am new to working with apache and mod_wsgi. But I do have little experience in django, so from some [tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hBMVVruB9Vs) I tried to run django app through apache webserver using mod_wsgi.
I created mysite in `/var/www/`
then in `mysite/application` I created `application.wsgi` ...

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.append('/var/www/mysite/application')

os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] = '/var/www/mysite/.python-egg'

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

and in /etc/httpd/sites-available I created file named mysite.conf ...

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName mysite.com
   ServerAdmin id@somewhere.com
   ServerAlias mysite.com
   DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite/   
<Directory /var/www/mysite>
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
  SetEnv DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE mysite.settings
</Directory>
WSGIDaemonProcess mysite processes=2 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP}
WSGIProcessGroup mysite
</Virtualhost>
```

Then I ran `a2ensite mysite.conf`, didn't showed any error.
Then in `/etc/httpd/hosts/` I added one line `my-ipddress mysite.com`
I gave permission `chmod 777` to all the above files and to folder `/var/www/mysite`. Now when I open `mysite.com` on browser I see apahce's default page nothing from django.
I am using fedora 21.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't put in anything in that configuration to serve your Django site via WSGI: you're missing the WSGIScriptAlias line (see [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/):

```
WSGIScriptAlias /  /var/www/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py
```

Note that you shouldn't really be putting things in /var/www; and also you shouldn't need to create your own WSGI file, Django creates one for you when you create a project.

Comment: In start I didn't put files in /var/www/ but it was not working so I thought of moving things in it .
and I added WSGIScriptAlias in mysite.conf but no change....

Comment: Did you reload Apache?

Comment: Take a look at [the following tutorial](http://www.unixmen.com/configure-django-with-apache-centos-7/) for a working example of @DanielRoseman's explanation.